# App does not send and receive SMS

Tags: android

I've written the following code that receives SMS and sends back the same SMS to the sender.
The code is running perfectly in Emulator but when I run the code in Mobile it doesn't receive and send an SMS.

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
   public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) 
   {
      //---get the SMS message passed in---
      Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
      SmsMessage[] msgs = null;

      String messageRecieved ="";     
      String result="";
      if (bundle != null)
      {
         //---retrieve the SMS message received---
         Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
         msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
         for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++)
         {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
            messageRecieved += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
         }

         //---display the new SMS message---
         Toast.makeText(context, "Sms Recieved: "+messageRecieved,
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         sms.sendTextMessage(sendersPhoneNumber, null, messageRecieved, null, null);
         Toast.makeText(context, "Sms sent back to Sender With Requested Contacts"
            ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I have registered the receiver with proper permission in manifest.
It works fine in the emulator but not on the phone.

It doesn't show toast.

Comment: see this it is useful [ http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android)

Comment: Is the phone using the native android messaging app or is the messaging done through some other third party application? If it is a third party application, then the messages bypass the content provider. Hence the broadcast receiver won't work.

Comment: the phone is using native android messaging app. but the receiver is not working in any case , when sms is send by 3 rd party app or by native sms application of android.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your real device might be the low memory problem. Either you have installed some big apps in your phone or the memory is running out of stack.
We all know that a SMS is about 20 or 30 KB only, but sometimes we need more than 20 MB of space in our phone, for receiving an SMS.

The solution to this problem is to move your data from phone memory to the SD Card.